# How to increment character data type in Ant script?

Tags: ant

Example:

```
<project name="num" default="jav">
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
  <!-- IF and Conditional task inbuild taskdef  --> 

  <target name="jav">
    <property file="proper.properties"/>
    <math result="index" operand1="${index}"
       operation="+" operand2="1" datatype="int"/>
    <echo message="index=${index}"/>
    <echo file="proper.properties" message="index=${index}"/> 
  </target>
</project>
```

In `proper.properties`, I have that `index=1A`. I'm able to increment the integer part but not character part.

I have one variable `index=1A`. I want to increment this number after each build process.

Suppose I have done the first build, then it should be `index=2B`. That is, I want to increment the integer as well as the character value (`1A`, `2B`, `3C`, ...) in Ant script.

Is this possible in Ant?

Comment: Use inline "script" task. I personally use Beanshell to do some char processing, like spliting string with certain parts.... Check this: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
<project name="test" default="init">

    <property name="init.value" value="1A"/>

    <scriptdef name="increase.label" language="javascript">
        <attribute name="value" />
        <attribute name="property" />
        <![CDATA[
       var initVal = attributes.get("value");
             var finalVal = String.fromCharCode(initVal.charAt(0) + 1);

       for(i = 1; i < initVal.length(); i++)
             {
               finalVal = finalVal.concat(String.fromCharCode(initVal.charAt(i) + 1));
             }
       project.setProperty(attributes.get("property"), finalVal);
     ]]>
    </scriptdef>


    <target name="init">
        <increase.label value="1A" property="result"/>
        <echo message="Result is : ${result}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

You need to have java 1.6 or later to use this of course.

Output :

```
init:
     [echo] Result is : 2B
```

Edit :

Now you want to increase the number not the character. Use `parseInt(string, radix)`.

I am not sure what you want to do with letters though. There you will have to add a new letter.

Comment: when i m taking `init.value=9I` then it's incrementing it to  `:J` but i want it to `10J` how can i do it

Comment: Well this will also happen with The letters. What happens when you go to Z? The increment is in char so after 9 in ASCII comes : which is what you get. In your question you were talking about character data. Now you are talking about numbers. You could do this either by parsing the number, or by adding logic which will do this for you. I  would go with the first option.

Comment: here my requirement is if i will take 1A then it should be increment like 1A,2B,3C....10J,11K,........means both data should be increase means Integer as well as Character...

Comment: @picnic4u You didn't answer to the other question. What happens when you reach Z?

Comment: @picnic4u And what is the desired output?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5014/discussion-between-picnic4u-and-faileddev)